# Are there NPCs in deep space?

Tags: elite-dangerous

In non-populated areas of space, as in those without stations, is it possible to have NPCs interdict / attack you?   I keep seeing salvageable crafts appear as spawns within various systems.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the answer to this is no, since NPC spawns are probably based on population, but I'm not 100%

Comment: I agree with @Unionhawk but I'm not positive either. NPCs may not spawn out in deep space, but signal sources might, which may give rise to NPC encounters? I'm not a deep spacer myself, curious to know the answer as well.

Comment: Not sure about NPCs spawning in deep space, but they can certainly follow you. They even follow you for thousands of lightyears sometimes.

Comment: @Mystery I believe that was a bug and should have been fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No!**

and yes!

The answer to the question in your title is clearly no! While there are salvageable craft from time to time, there are no NPC that could interdict or attack you. That being said, deep space is not the same as non-populated space without stations. NPCs will continue to show up outside of The Bubble (populated space) for some time.

However, as soon as you put a few long distance jumps (50 to 100 LY in total) between you and inhabited space you are safe from NPCs.